# QR Iteration convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, qr-decomposition

Assuming $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ are eigenvectors of matrix $\mathbf A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, there is $$\left(\mathbf I-\mathbf x_1\mathbf x_1^\top\right)\mathbf A\left(\mathbf I-\mathbf x_1\mathbf x_1^\top\right)\mathbf x_2 = \lambda_2 \left(\mathbf I-\mathbf x_1\mathbf x_1^\top\right)\mathbf x_2.$$

(Darve "Numerical linear algebra with Julia 2021", pp 159)

Why is $\left(\mathbf I-\mathbf x_1\mathbf x_1^\top\right)\mathbf A = \lambda_2? $

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Could you please add a link to the source you reference, if this is available online.

Comment: The question makes no sense, because $\lambda_2$ (presumably) is a number (the eigenvalue associated with $x_2,$ I would guess) while $(I-x_1x_1^\prime)A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: The source is not available online

Comment: Here is the snap of the relevant page OP referenced: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xihea.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

We assume A is a symmetric matrix in your problem.

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are distinct, then their eigenvectors are orthogonal. Otherwise if the you would need to *choose* $x_1,x_2$ to be orthogonal.
so $x_1^T x_2 =0$.

Also $Ax_2 = \lambda_2 x_2$, assuming $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of the corresponding eigenvector $x_i$

Comment: Eigenvectors are not necessarily orthogonal: it appears you implicitly assume $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks @whuber - added symmetry assumption.

Comment: Apologies, I want to upvote this but: 1. something happened in the sentence "Otherwise if the you would need to(...)", what do you mean? :) 2. While the OP doesn't say it, in p. 158, the book reads "*we will assume that $A$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues so that $|\lambda_1|  >$ $|\lambda_2| >$ $\dots >$ $|\lambda_n| $(but $A$ doesn't have to be symmetric).*